# How to update redux state further down the tree

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux

For a given reducer, my redux state tree typically looks something like this:

```
{
  someField: 'some value',
  // ... more fields
  metadata: {
    pending: false,
    fetched: true,
  }
}
```

Typically, when I do an async request, I fire a `SOME_ACTION_REQUEST` action, which sets the `metadata.pending` property to true. It's reset to false again when the matching `SOME_ACTION_RESPONSE` or `SOME_ACTION_ERROR` event trickles in later.

However, the way I update the state is a bit verbose:

```
case actions.SOME_ACTION_REQUEST: {
  return {
    ...state,
    metadata: { ...state.metadata, pending: true },
  };
}
```

Is there a simpler way of doing this?

`Object.assign({}, state, { metadata: { pending: true } })` isn't very readable either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cleaner/shorter way to update nested state in Redux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592078/cleaner-shorter-way-to-update-nested-state-in-redux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go for a nested structure of reducer.

where have a function/reducer naming metadata, call this to change the fields.

Example code

```
const metadata = (state = [], action = {}) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actions.SOME_ACTION_REQUEST::
            return {...state, ...action.payload.metadata};

        default:
            return state;
    }
};
const someReducer = (state = initalState, action = {}) => {
    let metadata = {};
    switch (action.type) {
        case actions.SOME_ACTION_REQUEST: {
            metadata = metadata(state.metadata, action)
            return {
                ...state,
                ...metadata
                };
            }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

That's a pretty typical example of doing immutable data updates.  You may want to read through the new [Structuring Reducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/StructuringReducers.html) section of the Redux docs for some further information, particularly the [Prerequisite Concepts](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/PrerequisiteConcepts.html) and [Immutable Update Patterns](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html) pages.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it is actually a downside of Redux, and not only -- if you would use MobX, you'd have the same issue. So, the answer is just to generalize it somehow -- write a reducers factory, which will get constants as arguments, and merge them just once, and reuse it for all async actions.

[I've created a library](https://github.com/Bloomca/redux-tiles) for exactly this issue, so feel free to look at it. Also, just keep in mind that raw Redux is pretty verbose anyway, and try to grasp your domain model in the best way.
Your example will look like that:

```
import { createTile } from 'redux-tiles';

const someTile = createTile({
  type: ['some', 'example'],
  fn: ({ api, params }) => api.get('/some/request', params),
});

dispatch(actions.some.example(params));
selectors.some.example(state)); // { isPending: true, error: null, data: null }
```

Data from the last selector will be updated automatically after response will be gotten -- so no need to write such stuff manually.

Another problem is nested updates, and you'd have to do the same thing, but with bigger amount of verbosity, which I always tried to solve. But, of course, it is a pretty simple library, which tries only to cover simple use-cases -- for complex ones, I definitely recommend you to try something custom-tailored.