# deep change state with variable index

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to follow the instructions found in [Cleaner/shorter way to update nested state in Redux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592078/cleaner-shorter-way-to-update-nested-state-in-redux#) [the accepted answer]

The thing is in my particular case, i have a layer that really depends on which model the user has selected up to that point. My structure:

[image: my structure]

Now in my reducer, i've tried (just want to change the favorite leaf to true):

```
let newStateForFavorites = {...state, models: {
            ...state.models,
            62416: {
                ...state.models.62416,
                details: {
                    ...state.models.62416.details,
                    favorited: true
                }
            }
        }};
```

Javascript complains. If i try to extract it to a var:

```
const currentModelToFav = action.payload.model_id;
let newStateForFavorites = {...state, models: {
            ...state.models,
            currentModelToFav: {
                ...state.models.currentModelToFav,
                details: {
                    ...state.models.currentModelToFav.details,
                    favorited: true
                }
            }
        }};
```

Javascript does not associate the const. And it errors out -currentModelToFav is undefined-

Ideas of what i'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Nested state is generally managed by nested reducers (combined via [`combineReducers`](https://redux.js.org/api-reference/combinereducers))

Comment: @naomik I'm doing that. This is just one of the reducers with form just a part of the stored state..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use a variable as a property name you'll have to use these constructs:

```
{[variableName] : value}
```

and

```
{propertyName : variable[variableName]}
```

So, your object literal will become:

```
const currentModelToFav = action.payload.model_id;
let newStateForFavorites = {...state, models: {
        ...state.models,
       [currentModelToFav]: {
            ...state.models[currentModelToFav],
            details: {
                ...state.models[currentModelToFav].details,
                favorited: true
            }
        }
    }};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) to pull an object key using a variable:

```
const currentModelToFav = action.payload.model_id;
let newStateForFavorites = {
    ...state, 
    models: {
        ...state.models,
        [currentModelToFav]: {
            ...state.models[currentModelToFav],
            details: {
                ...state.models[currentModelToFav].details,
                favorited: true
            }
        }
    }
};
```