# React-Native Persist object of objects with redux-persist

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-persist

I have this state in redux:

```
draft: {
    temporary: { clientId: null, shoppingCart: [] },
},
```

in my shoppingCart, I push some objects with *react-addons-update*:

```
const newState = { ...state };
let cart = newState.draft.temporary.shoppingCart;
cart = update(cart, { $push: [{ id: 1, quantity: 3 }] });
newState.draft.temporary.shoppingCart = cart;
return newState;
```

and my newState in the app is:

```
draft: {
        temporary: { clientId: null, shoppingCart: [
            {id: 1, qnt: 3},
        ]},
    },
```

I config my *products* reducer with:

```
products: persistReducer(products: {
    key: 'products',
    storage,
    whitelist: ['draft'],   
}, products),
```

but my store isn't persisted once the application is reloaded.

UPDATE:

example solution that works:

```
newState.draft = { ...newState.draft, temporary: { ...newState.draft.temporary, shoppingCart: [ ...newState.draft.temporary.shoppingCart, { id: 1, qnt: 3 } ]}};
```

solution without *react-addons-update* that doesn't work:

```
newState.draft.temporary.shoppingCart = [ ...newState.draft.temporary.shoppingCart, { id: payload.id, quantity: 1 } ];
```

There is a "cleaner solution"??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final solution that I have used was changing reducer:

```
  const newDraft = { ...state.draft };
  let cart = state.draft.temporary.shoppingCart;

  const index = _.findIndex(cart, { id: payload.id });

  if (index === -1) cart = update(cart, { $push: [{ id: payload.id, quantity: 1 }] });
  else cart = update(cart, { [index]: { quantity: { $set: cart[index].quantity + 1 } } });

  newDraft.temporary.shoppingCart = cart;

  return { ...state, draft: { ...newDraft } };
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that can work for your case:

`import { persistCombineReducers, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';`

`const draftPersistConfig = {
  key: 'draft',
  storage: AsyncStorage
};`

`const reducers = {
  products: persistReducer(draftPersistConfig, products),
  // ...other reducers if you have any
}`

`const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  debug: true,
  whitelist: ['draft']
};`

`persistCombineReducers(persistConfig, reducers);` should return you rootReducer that you can use to create store

Comment: Thanks, but this solution isn't working for me.
The problem that changing an object child somehow is not notified to the redux persistor.
Example: 

This is working -> newState.draft = { ...newState.draft, temporary: { ...newState.draft.temporary, shoppingCart: [ ...newState.draft.temporary.shoppingCart, { id: 1, qnt: 3 } ]}};

This isn't working -> newState.draft.temporary.shoppingCart = [ ...newState.draft.temporary.shoppingCart, { id: payload.id, quantity: 1 } ];

I need to find a cleaner solution ;)

Comment: I added example in main question :)

Comment: I see, updating nested state can be tricky and the problem with example that doesn't work is because you're mutating the state instead of creating new one. So if you're looking for just a cleaner way of updating redux state here is some good explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592078/cleaner-shorter-way-to-update-nested-state-in-redux