# React -Update a nested object in redux state of an unknown depth

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

When a user loads a blog post page, a post is fetched and its comments and subcomments are stored in the Redux state with the following structure:

```
forumPost: {
             id: #,
             data: {object},
             comments: [
               {
                 id: #,
                 data: {object},
                 comments: [
                   {
                     id: #,
                     data: {object},
                     comments: [...]
                   },
                   ...
                 ]
               },{
                 id: #,
                 data: {object},
                 comments: [...]
               },
              ...
           }
```

When a user posts a new comment/subcomment, it is posted to the database and locally added to the Redux state. I am having problems with the second part

I created a function for finding the path to the parent comment of the comment being posted but am having trouble injecting the new comment into the current state.

```
const findPath = (comments, parentId) => {
  let path = [];

  const findIndex = (arry, count) => {
    for (; count < arry.length; count++) {
      if (arry[count].id === parentId) {
        path = "forumPost.comments[" + count + "].comments";
        return true;
      }
      if (arry[count].comments && arry[count].comments.length > 0) {
        if (findIndex(arry[count].comments, 0)) {
          path = path
            .split("forumPost")
            .join("forumPost.comments[" + count + "]");
          return true;
        }
      }
    }
  };

  findIndex(comments, 0);
  return path;             //Returns the parent's path as 'forumPost.comments[a].comments[b].comments'
};
```

I can create an entirely new state, add the new comment, and replace the old state, but doing so is expensive and (as I understand it) makes it impossible for a component to tell if the Redux state (mapped to props) has changed.

So, having done some research I have come to understand that redux treats updating and replacing the state differently and what I want to do is update the state.

- https://reactjs.org/docs/update.html
- [Cleaner/shorter way to update nested state in Redux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592078/cleaner-shorter-way-to-update-nested-state-in-redux)
- [Object spread vs. Object.assign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32925460/object-spread-vs-object-assign)

I’ve tried to use .update(), …spreads, and [dot-prop](https://github.com/debitoor/dot-prop-immutable), but haven’t been able to get them to work (most likely because I have been using them wrong)… and that’s why I am here. How do you update the state with a new comment object to one of the comments arrays of an unknown depth?

Also, I now know that its best practice to keep your redux state as shallow as possible. But the current structure is what it is.

Comment: Check this very important recipe: [normalizing state shape](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape)

Comment: Maybe [this set function](https://gist.github.com/amsterdamharu/659bb39912096e74ba1c8c676948d5d9) can help you.